# ggplot2 gives error message inside a package but works if source the R function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I wrote an R package with many functions. Everything works. But when I run one function which uses ggplot2 and 2 data.frames for the same plot, it gives error. But if I source or do step by step it works. 
What is the difference? 
Why it doesn't work from the package ?

Example:

```
install_github("mbertalan/iPsychCNV")
library(iPsychCNV)
# CNV.Res and roi are loaded from the package.
PlotAllCNVs(df=CNV.Res, Name="Test.png", roi=roi)
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

But if I copy the code at github (PlotAllCNVs.R), paste in R and re-run the same command. It works, creating the plot and returning a data.frame.

The code:

```
b <- ggplot(tmp2, aes(Start, Indx))
b <- b + geom_segment(aes(x = Start, y = Indx, xend = Stop, yend = Indx, colour=as.factor(Class)))
b <- b + scale_colour_manual(values = c("ROI" = Colors[6],"q" = Colors[5],"p" = Colors[4], "1" = Colors[1], "3" = Colors[2], "4" = Colors[3], "0"=Colors[7], "2"=Colors[8]))
b <- b + facet_wrap(~ Titles, scales = "free", ncol = NCOL) 
b <- b + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(Start, Stop)), tmp2ROI, alpha=0.2)
```

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong.  Did you import that necessary functions to the package?  It would be helpful, at the very least, you provided that actual error.

Comment: That appears to be an error with `grid.text`.  Make sure the proper functions are imported.  A question with the same error is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115701/error-adding-grid-text-to-ggplot) but again without something reproducible we can only guess.

Comment: that is a start, please move your comment to your question above and if you can, please provide some sample data to reproduce the error.

Comment: As I said, I can only guess when I cannot reproduce your error.  Please update your question and include some sample data to reproduce the error.

Comment: The only way to reproduce the error is installing the package and running the function from the package. If you copy the code and the Rdata it will work. I will be grateful if you can send me this information.

Comment: I downloaded the package and copied the code but got another error with your data: `Error in n/ncol : non-numeric argument to binary operator
`

Comment: Odd, NCOL is a input variable for face_wrap. The default is 2. Are you sure sure you copy the whole code ? Check out the ggplot2 part of the code:    b <- b + facet_wrap(~ Titles, scales = "free", ncol = NCOL)

Comment: I removed line by line to find when the error happens. The problem seems to be when I do geom_segment. Everything before that works.      b <- b + geom_segment(aes(x = Start, y = Indx, xend = Stop, yend = Indx, colour=as.factor(Class)))

Answer (score 0):

Passing the dataframe in ggplot seems to create a layer. Then it can not add to the plot (in the package). However, it works if the plot is geom_point (I tested it).

```
b <- ggplot(tmp2, aes(Start, Indx))
b <- b + geom_segment(aes(x = Start, y = Indx, xend = Stop, yend = Indx, colour=as.factor(Class)))
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

If you add the dataframe in the geom_segment it works:

```
b <- ggplot() + geom_segment(data=tmp2, aes(x = Start, y = Indx, xend = Stop, yend = Indx, colour=as.factor(Class)))
```

For some reason, inside the package, it can not overwrite the layer. Then gives you the error:

```
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```