# ggsave() after ggplot() with annotation

Tags: annotations

I am trying to save figures made with ggplot with annotations made with grid.text into tiffs using ggsave. However, ggsave does not incorporate the annotation. I tried using grid.arrange and arrangeGrob (as suggested in previous posts) but it says neither function can be found. It seems like some changes have been made to the packages since those answers were posted?

`{r}
    require(reshape2)
    require(lsr)
require(ggplot2)
require(ez)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)
source("summarySE.R")`

    `{r}
    AggregateBW2 = summarySE(AggregateBW1, measurevar="BW", groupvars=c("Cond","Iso","within"))
    figure = ggplot(AggregateBW2, aes(x=Cond, y=BW, group=within)) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="#999999", colour="black") +
    facet_grid(Iso ~ .) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=BW-se, ymax=BW+se), 
                  width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
    scale_x_discrete(name="Surgical condition") + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Body Weight (g)") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=22),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=22),
        strip.text.y=element_text(size=18))
    #+ grid.text(unit(.985,"npc"),0.5,label = "Isoflurane Percentage", rot = 270, gp=gpar(fontsize=22), check=TRUE)
    paperfigure = grid.arrange(figure, ncol = 1, bottom = "footnote")
    ggsave(file="newbodyweight-final.tiff", paperfigure)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grid.text()`, try `annotate()`. That's because `grid.text()` adds an external annotation that is not actually saved in the structure of your plot (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115836).

In a very simplified example, the code below created [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrhtw.png:):

```
figure=ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(Species~.)+
  annotate(geom="text", label = "Isoflurane Percentage", y=6, x=3)

ggsave(file="newbodyweight-final.png", figure)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer.